# How can I determine which element is causing an overflow?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, parseint, int32, overflowexception

I've got this code:

```
String testData = File.ReadAllText("siteQueryTest.txt");
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(testData);
List<SiteQuery> sitequeries =
 (from sitequery in xmlDoc.Descendants("SiteQuery")
  select new SiteQuery
  {
      Id = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("Id").Value),
      UPCPackSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("UPCPackSize").Value),
      UPC_Code = sitequery.Element("UPC_Code").Value,
      crvId = sitequery.Element("crvId").Value,
      dept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("dept").Value),
      description = sitequery.Element("description").Value,
      openQty = Convert.ToDouble(sitequery.Element("openQty").Value),
      packSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("packSize").Value),
      subDept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("subDept").Value),
      unitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitCost").Value),
      unitList = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitList").Value),
      vendorId = sitequery.Element("vendorId").Value,
      vendorItem = sitequery.Element("vendorItem").Value,
  }).ToList<SiteQuery>();
```

testData is:

```
<SiteQueries><SiteQuery><Id>00006000002</Id><UPCPackSize>1</UPCPackSize><UPC_Code>00006000002</UPC_Code><crvId></crvId><dept>8</dept><description>ZZ</description><openQty>0.0</openQty><packSize>1</packSize><subDept>80</subDept><unitCost>1.25</unitCost><unitList>5.0</unitList><vendorId>CONFLICT</vendorId><vendorItem>123456</vendorItem></SiteQuery>
. . . // gazillions of other SiteQuery "records"
<SiteQuery><Id>5705654</Id><UPCPackSize>1</UPCPackSize><UPC_Code>5705654</UPC_Code><crvId></crvId><dept>2</dept><description>what do you want</description><openQty>0.0</openQty><packSize>1</packSize><subDept>0</subDept><unitCost>0.55</unitCost><unitList>1.62</unitList><vendorId></vendorId><vendorItem></vendorItem></SiteQuery></SiteQueries>
```

But I get the following runtime exception with this code and data:

```
System.OverflowException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2146233066
  _message=Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
  HResult=-2146233066
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
       at Sandbox.Form1.<button56_Click>b__e(XElement sitequery) in c:\HoldingTank\Sandbox\Form1.cs:line 2041
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
    . . .
  InnerException:
```

There are several int values (4) in each xml "record"; there are thousands of records. How can I, without trying to put on a Rainman hat (which doesn't fit me very well) determine just which value is the problematic one causing the overflow or underflow?

If it's an underflow (the exception msg says both "OverflowException" and "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32", could it be cause by an empty value for one of those four int members? If so, how can I tell it to consider an empty value as 0?

Comment: Catch the exception, break in the handler, inspect vars and progess?

Comment: Why not use decimal instead of int?

Comment: `It says: `c:\HoldingTank\Sandbox\Form1.cs:line 2041` which line is that?

Comment: The `Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("foo").Value)` begs for a custom method that takes `sitequery` and `Foo` as arguments. You would catch the culprit in no time.

Comment: @DrKoch: Why would that help?

Comment: @jessehouwing: It is "select new SiteQuery"

Comment: Well, that UPC code could definitely be too large for an int32 just based on the number of digits. If the leading number is a 1 it will overflow.

Comment: @MartinJames: There's no user code to break at.

Comment: @mikez: It looks like the UPC code is one of a few fields that don't get converted.  Possibly left as a string.

Comment: I would add you could change siteQuery constructors to do the argument handling and validation  instead of inside the LINQ expression which would make trapping the exception easier.

Comment: Since your `Id` has leading digits, I'd use a `string` for it anyway, or you'll lose those digits.

Comment: @mikez: Yes, as Ben Voigt says, UPC code is a string.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I meant the Id.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon yea, I meant the Id, it is the same value but it is converted to an integer. The obvious solution is to move that into a method and put in some logging so you can find the offending entry.

Comment: Comment out all the `Convert.Int32` lines. Uncomment them one-by-one until it breaks again. Make which ever field causes the problem with `uint` (if it can't be negative anyway) or `Int64`. Unless you have a reason to believe one of the items in your dataset is wrong by being out-of-range, then you need to handle it anyway by using a field large enough to hold the value.

Comment: I made Id a String, took out the converting of it to an int, and voila! The bluebirds of happiness have returned to their proper place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why most coders end up using extension methods, but not LINQ.  Rewrite as:

```
private static SiteQuery ParseSiteQuery(XElement sitequery)
{
  return new SiteQuery
  {
      Id = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("Id").Value),
      UPCPackSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("UPCPackSize").Value),
      UPC_Code = sitequery.Element("UPC_Code").Value,
      crvId = sitequery.Element("crvId").Value,
      dept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("dept").Value),
      description = sitequery.Element("description").Value,
      openQty = Convert.ToDouble(sitequery.Element("openQty").Value),
      packSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("packSize").Value),
      subDept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("subDept").Value),
      unitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitCost").Value),
      unitList = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitList").Value),
      vendorId = sitequery.Element("vendorId").Value,
      vendorItem = sitequery.Element("vendorItem").Value,
  };
}
```

and then do

```
List<SiteQuery> sitequeries = xmlDoc.Descendants("SiteQuery")
                                    .Select(ParseSiteQuery).ToList();
```

Now when the exception occurs, you'll break inside this conversion function, with `sitequery` in scope, giving immediate knowledge of what particular XElement caused the failure.

Then you can use quickwatch expressions to quickly find out what initializer caused the exception.  Or even write separate statements for each property assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working:

```
   private void button42_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ArrayList arrList = 
    FetchSiteQuery("http://localhost:21608/api/sitequery/getall/dbill/ppus/42"); 
        String omnivore = "<SiteQueries>";
        foreach (String s in arrList) //- see siteQueryData.png
        {
            omnivore += s;
        }
        omnivore += "</SiteQueries>";

        String messedUpJunk = "<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
    instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS\">";
        omnivore = omnivore.Replace(messedUpJunk, String.Empty);
        omnivore = omnivore.Replace("</ArrayOfSiteQuery>", String.Empty);

        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(omnivore);
        List<SiteQuery> sitequeries = 
    xmlDoc.Descendants("SiteQuery").Select(GetSiteQueryForXMLElement).ToList();
    }

    private static SiteQuery GetSiteQueryForXMLElement(XElement sitequery)
    {
        return new SiteQuery
        {
            Id = sitequery.Element("Id").Value,
            UPCPackSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("UPCPackSize").Value),
            UPC_Code = sitequery.Element("UPC_Code").Value,
            crvId = sitequery.Element("crvId").Value,
            dept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("dept").Value),
            description = sitequery.Element("description").Value,
            openQty = Convert.ToDouble(sitequery.Element("openQty").Value),
            packSize = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("packSize").Value),
            subDept = Convert.ToInt32(sitequery.Element("subDept").Value),
            unitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitCost").Value),
            unitList = Convert.ToDecimal(sitequery.Element("unitList").Value),
            vendorId = sitequery.Element("vendorId").Value,
            vendorItem = sitequery.Element("vendorItem").Value,
        };
    }
```