# Why can the type arguments not be inferred, and how can I specify them explicitly?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, extension-methods, generic-type-argument

This code, adapted from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826092/how-can-i-determine-which-element-is-causing-an-overflow) works in a .NET 4.5.1 app in Visual Studio 2013:

```
private void button42_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<SiteQuery> sitequeries = GetListOfSiteQueries();
    foreach (SiteQuery sitequery in sitequeries)
    {
        // TODO: Insert into table
    }
}

private List<SiteQuery> GetListOfSiteQueries()
{
    ArrayList arrList = 
FetchSiteQuery("http://localhost:21608/api/sitequery/getall/dbill/ppus/42");
    String omnivore = "<SiteQueries>";
    foreach (String s in arrList)
    {
        omnivore += s;
    }
    omnivore += "</SiteQueries>";
    String unwantedPreamble = "<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS\">";
    omnivore = omnivore.Replace(unwantedPreamble, String.Empty);
    omnivore = omnivore.Replace("</ArrayOfSiteQuery>", String.Empty);
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(omnivore);
    List<SiteQuery> sitequeries = 
xmlDoc.Descendants("SiteQuery").Select(GetSiteQueryForXMLElement).ToList();
    return sitequeries;
}

private static SiteQuery GetSiteQueryForXMLElement(XElement sitequery)
{
    return new SiteQuery
    {
        Id = sitequery.Element("Id").Value,
        . . .
```

However, the same code in a .NET 3.5, Compact Framework/Windows CE app in VS 2008 fails to compile with "*The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*"

It fails on this line:

```
List<SiteQuery> sitequeries = xmlDoc.Descendants("SiteQuery").Select(GetSiteQueryForXMLElement).ToList();
```

Why does identical code work in one case but not the other; is it because of the recalcitrant's code Windows CE-ness and/or because it's .NET 3.5 instead of the newer 4.5.1?

If one or both of those limitations is/are the issue, is there a workaround, or is it a "back to the coding board" situation?

Comment: Try `Select<YourTypeHere>(GetSiteQueryForXMLElements)`

Comment: @EricJ.: You'd need to specify the source *and* result types - there are two type parameters on `Select`.

Comment: Good point, I see that reflected in your answer (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference changed in VS2010 (IIRC) - basically the compiler became slightly more capable. It's not a matter of .NET itself changing.

Two simple options:

- Use a lambda expression instead:

  ```
  .Select(x => GetSiteQueryForXMLElement(x))
  ```
- Specify the type arguments with a method group conversion:

  ```
  .Select<XElement, SiteQuery>(GetSiteQueryForXMLElement);
  ```

Either should work fine.

Comment: If I swap List out for IEnumerable, either one works, yes; thanks!